# MySQL keeps shutting down: /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'set-variable=key_buffer_size=32M'

Tags: mysql, shutdown

My MySQL keep shutdown automatically with this error report:

```
200405 23:31:39 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
200405 23:31:39 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
200405 23:31:39 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
200405 23:31:39 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
200405 23:31:39 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
200405 23:31:39 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
200405 23:31:39 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
200405 23:31:39 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
200405 23:31:39 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
200405 23:31:39  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
200405 23:31:40 InnoDB: 5.5.62 started; log sequence number 14465811850
200405 23:31:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'set-variable=key_buffer_size=32M'
200405 23:31:40 [ERROR] Aborting

200405 23:31:40  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
200405 23:31:41  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 14465811850
200405 23:31:41 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

When I try to log into MySQL it says:

> DBI connect failed : Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I try to open /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock and can not found mysqld.sock

This happened after I tried to set key_buffer_size=32M by using webmin.

How to make it stop trying to set the key_buffer_size?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Of the configuration package?

Comment: It seems that MySQL config in webmin has not been upgraded in at least a decade.  Don't depend on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the Module Configuration for mysql you find the path to my.cnf

[image]

Edit this  file and remove the line with key_buffer_size=32M and save it.

And then start the server.

[Webmin information on mysql](https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/MySQL_Database_Server)

Comment: I've remove key_buffer_size from my.cnf but it still wont start, and the error message is still the same

Comment: is it because the "set-variable=" before key_buffer_size=32M? how to stop mysql from sending this command?

Comment: mysql start twith the my.cnf file specified.. If you remived the line and save d the file it should noz give the error. How do you put it there in the first place?

Comment: I finally found the problem

in my.cnf there's a line like this
set-variable=before key_buffer_size=32M

I remove all of it, including set-variable. and my database work find

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: good please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
After I # the variable I got another error of a non existing variable.
So I deleted the my.cnf in `etc/`. I guess this means use default variables.
After that all works in good order.